# Redmine Not Recognizing Migration File to Change DB

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, migration, redmine

Essentially I am trying to add a new column to an existing Redmine database table through a plugin.

To my knowledge, the main command for migrating to the database through a plugin is:

```
rake redmine:plugins:migrate
```

yet when I run that command, on my local machine it says that it is migrating all the plugins i have installed, however it is not updating the database. Are there any checks I can do to make sure that redmine is recognizing which database to migrate to?

For example, in one of my plugins I simple want to add a new field **:foo** of type **:datetime** to the users table with the following migration file:

```
class AddColumnIssuePosition < ActiveRecord::Migration

    def self.up
        change_table :user do |t|
            t.column :foo, :datetime
        end
    end

    def self.down
        change_table :user do |t|
            t.remove :foo
        end
    end

end
```

I run the migration rake command and it says that it has migrated the plugin, however it doesnt give any details on the new column addition "foo" to the "users" table...

```
Migrating user_foo (User Foo Plugin)...
```

It just spouts out that line and it ends there. No changes found on the users table.

Forgive me as I am somewhat new to rails.

Answer (score 0):

Change your migration to look like below:

```
class AddColumnIssuePosition < ActiveRecord::Migration

  def change
    add_column :users, :foo, :datetime
  end

end
```